# How does require_once "check if the file has already been included"?

Tags: php

I assume it doesn't actually hash the file contents, does it stick all of the `require`'d pathnames into an internal hash table?

The context for this is that I'm getting some (redeclaration) warnings that would make sense if `require_once` was getting confused by slightly different paths to the same file, and I'd obviously rather not load files multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_once()` will only keep track of unique file access paths.

- If the same content inside two files accessed, they will treated as different files (intuitive)
- If the same physical file is accessed via two different paths, it
  will be treated as different files. (less intuitive)
- If a physical file is accessed, later a symlink to the same physical file, it will be treated as different files (least intuitive)

Comment: Also in PHP versions under 5, Window path locations could get messed up with cases and windows adding "~" in paths. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: That all makes sense, I'll accept the answer when the min-time is up. Is this mentioned in the docs anywhere?

Comment: I researched this while creating an ugly hack for `require_once()` with symlinks, as I found nothing about that in the docs.

Comment: Ha. At least I'm not completely blind.

Comment: I think realpath has been removed to not be such a I/O burden when require'ing once. Normally autoloading is a good alternative to it because you have got more control.